# OTRS 3.2.* installation error on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, otrs

I have installed CentOS 6.5 x86_64 on VMWare Workstation 9.
Then run updates after it disabled SELinux.
Now I'm trying to install otrs 3.3.6 but I'm get an error as below. 
Have I challenges to fix it? Or it is a compatible issue?

```
Total size: 73 M
Installed size: 73 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum.
Error in PREIN scriptlet in rpm package otrs-3.3.6-01.noarch
Check OTRS user ... otrs exists.
usermod: user otrs is currently logged in
error: %pre(otrs-3.3.6-01.noarch) scriptlet failed, exit status 8
error:   install: %pre scriptlet failed (2), skipping otrs-3.3.6-01
 Verifying  : otrs-3.3.6-01.noarch                                         1/1 

 Failed:
  otrs.noarch 0:3.3.6-01
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue because I created otrs user before installation.